# I can't figure out why I am getting error "can't convert nil into String"

Tags: ruby

```
puts 'Please enter your age '
age=gets.chomp
age=age.to_i

if  age >=18
division='in the adult '

elsif age >=12
division='in the junior '

elsif age >=5
division='in the novice '

else    
puts 'We are sorry, but you are ineligible to play in the league at this time.'

end
puts 'Congratulations! You are '+division+'league.'

sleep 5
```

The error I get is this:

```
We are sorry, but you are ineligible to play in the league at this time.
:18:in `+': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Sorry. I only get the error if I enter 4 or less.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that message because `division` is nil.  In the case that none of your conditions are met the 'We are sorry' message is displayed, but no value is assigned to the `division` variable.

You can get rid of it by doing:

```
puts 'Congratulations! You are '+division+'league.' unless division.nil?
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Nothing like that appears in the text I'm using.

Comment: As @Still a kid mentions in his answer you're better off setting a value for `division` initially.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not initializing `division`, and it's thus set to nil.Initialize division like this:

```
division = 'in no'
```

Do that either in else block or before the first if.

Comment: How would I initialize division?

Comment: I've edited my answer. But it would be better to follow Richard Brown's answer i.e. using unless

Answer (score 0):

Just to show how your code can be more Ruby-like:

```
print 'Please enter your age: '
age = gets.chomp.to_i

division = case 
          when age >= 18
            'adult'

          when age >= 12
            'junior'

          when age >=5
            'novice' 

          else    
            nil

          end

if division
  puts "Congratulations! You are in the #{ division } league."
else
  puts 'We are sorry, but you are ineligible to play in the league at this time.'
end
```

I'm sure it could be tighter, but this is how I'd do it. Also, because the code checks to see if `division` is set, it won't return the error you're seeing.

Comment: Wow! OK I just tried to do the same thing using case and mine doesn't look nearly as neat as yours. Thank you for the insight.